# Allow empty cells in WPF Datagrid with Auto generated Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my WPF application that is bound to a collection:

```
public class MyPropertyCollection : ObservableCollection<MyProperty>
```

The property has nullable and non-nullable values.

```
public class MyProperty
{
    public int Required{ get; set; }
    public int? Optional{ get; set; }
}
```

The datagrid does not allow empty cell values for either of the properties.

Is there a way to allow it to take empty values for the cells if the value is nullable?

Note: The columns are generated automatically so they are not individually defined in the xaml. I am using .Net 4.6.1

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMyProperties">    </DataGrid>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not very clear about the specific situation you want to express. In the DataGrid, if the target value is Null, it will be displayed as an empty string in DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: Correct. But if I edit an existing value by blanking out the column then it shows an error (red rectangle around the cell), even though the value is nullable.

Comment: `The datagrid does not allow empty cell values for either of the properties.` It's allowed. `Is there a way to allow it to take empty values for the cells if the value is nullable?` So you want to display something such as 'NULL' in the cell if the source is null?

Comment: In other words, you want to make Nullable data source accept edit values from the DataGrid? Why not try to use `DataGrid.CellEditEnding` event?

Comment: Also you can using `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event, it allows you to do some other thing for current columns during the automatic column generation, and the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumn` event occurs after all the columns are automatically created.

Comment: I want to be able to leave the cell blank. A blank cell would correspond to a value of null. I have used DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn for other things but not sure how to achieve this. I will see if DataGrid.CellEditEnding will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get it done by setting the TargetNullValue programatically in AutoGeneratingColumn

```
private void DoAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridBoundColumn textCol = e.Column as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridBoundColumn;
    if (textCol != null)
    {
        textCol.Binding.TargetNullValue = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And the xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMyProperties" AutoGeneratingColumn="DoAutoGeneratingColumn">
</DataGrid>
```

By default the TargetNullValue is not set.
Initially I was also checking to see if the column was a nullable value but this is not required as it will automatically get an error if you have a blank cell for a value that cannot be null.

Note the above should work for the following column types: DataGridTextColumn, DataGridCheckBoxColumn, DataGridHyperlinkColumn.

Answer (score 1):

In the XAML you could just add `TargetNullValue=''` in your binding as in the following example

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Value, TargetNullValue=''}"
```